# Contact surface between circle and curved floor?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, calculus

First, consider an inelastic circle on a hard, flat floor, the shared contact surface between the two is some infinitesimally small length dx.

Consider a second case, where if the floor had some curvature with the same concavity as the circle, this shared contact surface would still be infinitesimally small, but it would have to be some magnitude larger than for the first case, no?

Finally, for a third case, consider the contact surface between the two as the floor's radius of curvature approaches that of the circle's radius. Of course when their radii are equal the shared contact surface is equal to the length of the floor, however how do we quantify the contact just before as r_floor -> r_circle?

This question has been on my mind today as I've been coding an un-related wheel physics simulation. Can this be quantified as a continuous function with asymptotic behaviour? Do you have any resources with consideration to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

In ideal geometric situations, circles and spheres can only have contact with the described plane surface at a single geometric point, an immeasurable distance. In the case of the ideal concave surface, if the radius of the surface is larger than the radius of the circle or sphere, then there will still only be contact at a single point. It is not in your question but if the surface were convex there could still only be one point of contact. These situations all assume that the circles or spheres stop in contact with the surface and are not bisected by it, and there is no material deformation.

Answer (score 0):

For inelastic contact the contact "patch" is always a single point, until the two radii are equal.

But you can approach this like a Hertzian contact with two conforming radii of $R_1$ and $R_2$ with the floor curvature greater than the circle radius $R_2 > R_1$

Now imagine the separation value between the two surfaces as a function of distance $x$ from the contact point as

$$ s(x) = \left( R_1 - \sqrt{R_1^2 -x^2} \right) - \left( R_2 - \sqrt{R_2^2 -x^2} \right) $$

Now find the equivalent radius $R_\star$ if a circle on a flat ground with the same separation function

$$ s(x) = R_\star - \sqrt{R_\star^2 -x^2} $$

The two functions match up to $\mathtt{O}(x^2)$ if $$R_\star = \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_2-R_1}$$

So if you have some treatment for a circle on flat, you convert the two curves into a single radius with the above expression.